# Reading mixed .csv in two lines in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, mixed-code

I 've a csv.file part of it given below

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs17 
$GPGGA, 142621.00, 4106.29338717, N, 02901.18386180, E, 5, 06, 7.2, 103.3\par
$SDDBT, 1.3, f, 0.3, M, 0.2, F*05\par
\par
$GPGGA, 142622.00, 4106.29339273, N, 02901.18387863, E, 5, 06, 7.2, 103.3\par
$SDDBT, 1.3, f, 0.3, M, 0.2, F*05\par
\par
$GPGGA, 142623.00, 4106.29339566, N, 02901.18386326, E, 5, 06, 7.2, 103.3\par
$SDDBT, 1.3, f, 0.3, M, 0.2, F*05\par
\par
.
.
.
```

I 've problems \par at the end of line since I can't read value 103.3
And I couldn't make the program reads 2 lines by 2 lines (skipping "\par" line) at the same time with mixed variables

this gets rits of /par but it is not formatted reading. I am unsure using "csvread or fscanf"

`fid = fopen('filename','r+'); 
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n', 'CommentStyle', '\','headerlines',2);
C = C{:}; fclose(fid);`

Comment: Here comes classical first comment: What have you tried so far? Part of your code or idea?

Comment: fid = fopen('filename','r+');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n', 'CommentStyle', '\','headerlines',2);
C = C{:};
fclose(fid);

this gets rits of /par but it is not formatted reading. I am unsure using "csvread or fscanf"

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if textscan is able to read every nth line but I would read your file line by line using fgets:

```
% Initialize arrays
GPGGAArray = [];
SDDBTArray = [];

% open file
fid = fopen('filename','r+');

% Skip 2 header lines
currentLine = fgets(fid);
currentLine = fgets(fid);

while ischar(currentLine)

    currentLine = fgets(fid);
    if currentLine == -1    
        break;
    end
    % line with GPGGA
    C1 = textscan(currentLine, '%s', 'Delimiter', ','); 

    currentLine = fgets(fid);
    if currentLine == -1    
        break;
    end

    GPGGAArray = [GPGGAArray; [str2double(C1{1,1}{2}), str2double(C1{1,1}{3}), str2double(C1{1,1}{5}),...
        str2double(C1{1,1}{7}), str2double(C1{1,1}{8}), str2double(C1{1,1}{9}), str2double(C1{1,1}{10}(1:end-4))]];

    % line with SDDBT
    C2 = textscan(currentLine, '%s', 'Delimiter', ','); 

    SDDBTArray = [SDDBTArray; [str2double(C2{1,1}{2}), str2double(C2{1,1}{4}), str2double(C2{1,1}{6}),...
        str2double(C2{1,1}{7}(3:end-4))]];

    % skip line with \par
    currentLine = fgets(fid);

end
% Close file
fclose(fid);
```

Please be aware that C1 and C2 are cell arrays with strings.

Comment: textscan isn't suitable for this case

Comment: Have you tried the code I offered? why it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and versions of it but the program warned for using of function textscan

Comment: this version has not problem but we shouldnt read the lines as a text, since there are numeric values

Comment: then how should we read? you need all the numbers in the file?

Comment: yes, I need many of them. We should read like CSV format but CSVREAD function in Matlab reads only numbers, not text.

Comment: I thought you could convert the read lines to numbers. Anyway, I did it for you. Check the updated code

Comment: it is logical but program warns "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent." why? it will change the size of array at every iteration. Should we make it 2D array? Row is nth data and column is values.

Comment: I have tried the code in my computer (Matlab 2012a) with the part of your csv file you have provided in our question and it works without any error. Be aware that I assumed: Your GPGGA line has 9 commas (10 variables) and SDDBT line 6 commas (7 variables). If your csv file has also different format, it will not work.

Comment: it gives same error in 2015a but creates the arrays we want.